# TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute '__getitem__'

Tags: python, scrapy

I'm currently getting this error and don't know what is means. Its a scrapy python project, this is the error I'm seeing:

```
  File "/bp_scraper/bp_scraper/httpmiddleware.py", line 22, in from_crawler
    return cls(crawler.settings)
  File "/bp_scraper/bp_scraper/httpmiddleware.py", line 12, in __init__
    if parts[1]:
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object has no attribute '__getitem__'
```

The code:

```
import re
import random
import base64
from scrapy import log
class RandomProxy(object):
    def __init__(self, settings):
        self.proxy_list = settings.get('PROXY_LIST')
        f = open(self.proxy_list)

        self.proxies = {}
        for l in f.readlines():
            parts = re.match('(\w+://)(\w+:\w+@)?(.+)', l)

            if parts[1]:
                parts[1] = parts[1][:-1]

            self.proxies[parts[0] + parts[2]] = parts[1]

        f.close()
    @classmethod
    def from_crawler(cls, crawler):
        return cls(crawler.settings)
```

Thanks in advance for your help!

Comment: `re.match` returns a [match object](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#match-objects), which does not overload the `[]` operator. Did you mean `re.findall` instead?

Comment: with python 3.6 this should work (see [documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.match.__getitem__))

Answer (score 21):

The result of a `re.match` call is a `SRE_Match` object, which does not support the `[]` operator (a.k.a. `__getitem__`).  I think you want

```
if parts is not None:
    if parts.group(1):
        <blah>
```

Unfortunately, `parts.group(1)` is not mutable, so you'll have to make another variable to hold the changes you want to make to it.

Comment: You can get rid of `is not None` part. `if parts` is same as `if parts is not None`.

Comment: I choose to be as explicit as possible in my Python code.  `if parts` is not exactly the same as `if parts is not None`; the former tests whether the current boolean interpretation of `parts` is `True`, while the latter explicitly tests whether `parts` has a value of `None`.  In this example they would evaluate to the same thing, but I would rather not teach readers shortcuts that turn out not to work in some future case.

Comment: This is no longer the case in Python 3.6, where you can use `[]`, see [docs](https://docs.python.org/3/whatsnew/3.6.html#re).

Answer (score 8):

You can not access the matched results as:

```
        if parts[1]:
            parts[1] = parts[1][:-1]
```

Instead do this,

```
        if parts:
            matched = parts.group(1)[:-1]
```

More on regex matched groups [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.MatchObject.groups)