# How come regex match objects aren't iterable even though they implement __getitem__?

Tags: python, iterable

As you may know, [implementing a `__getitem__` method makes a class iterable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/926574/why-does-defining-getitem-on-a-class-make-it-iterable-in-python):

```
class IterableDemo:
    def __getitem__(self, index):
        if index > 3:
            raise IndexError

        return index

demo = IterableDemo()
print(demo[2])  # 2
print(list(demo))  # [0, 1, 2, 3]
print(hasattr(demo, '__iter__'))  # False
```

However, this doesn't hold true for regex match objects:

```
>>> import re
>>> match = re.match('(ab)c', 'abc')
>>> match[0]
'abc'
>>> match[1]
'ab'
>>> list(match)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not iterable
```

It's worth noting that this exception isn't thrown in the `__iter__` method, because that method isn't even implemented:

```
>>> hasattr(match, '__iter__')
False
```

So, how is it possible to implement `__getitem__` without making the class iterable?

Comment: I can't even seem to subscript `match`...

Comment: @Sweeper `Match.__getitem__` was added in Python 3.6 https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.Match.__getitem__

Comment: @DeepSpace Ah... I was using 3.5.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [TypeError: '\_sre.SRE\_Match' object has no attribute '\_\_getitem\_\_'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22313702/typeerror-sre-sre-match-object-has-no-attribute-getitem)

Comment: @PedroLobito But that has no explanation?

Comment: Maybe helpful: https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7f0d59f3a83cf1a98398b8e5bdfb97c7a71216bd/Modules/_sre.c#L1329

Comment: @PedroLobito That's a completely different question, isn't it? My match objects **do** have a `__getitem__` method...

Comment: @Li357 Also https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/e42b705188271da108de42b55d9344642170aa2b/Modules/sre.h#L44-L53

Answer (score 60, accepted):

There are lies, damned lies and then there is Python documentation.

Having `__getitem__` for a class implemented in *C* is not enough for it to be iterable. That is because there are actually *2* places in the `PyTypeObject` where the `__getitem__` can be mapped to: [`tp_as_sequence`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.tp_as_sequence) and [`tp_as_mapping`](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.tp_as_mapping). Both have a slot for `__getitem__` ([[1]](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PySequenceMethods.sq_item), [[2]](https://docs.python.org/3/c-api/typeobj.html#c.PyMappingMethods.mp_subscript)).

Looking at the source of the [`SRE_Match`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7f0d59f3a83cf1a98398b8e5bdfb97c7a71216bd/Modules/_sre.c#L2687), `tp_as_sequence` is initialized to `NULL` whereas `tp_as_mapping` is defined.

The `iter()` built-in function, if called with one argument, will call the [`PyObject_GetIter`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7f0d59f3a83cf1a98398b8e5bdfb97c7a71216bd/Objects/abstract.c#L2541), which has the following code:

```
f = t->tp_iter;
if (f == NULL) {
    if (PySequence_Check(o))
        return PySeqIter_New(o);
    return type_error("'%.200s' object is not iterable", o);
}
```

It first checks the `tp_iter` slot (obviously `NULL` for `_SRE_Match` objects); and failing that, then *if* `PySequence_Check` returns true, a new sequence iterator, else a `TypeError` is raised.

[`PySequenceCheck`](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/7f0d59f3a83cf1a98398b8e5bdfb97c7a71216bd/Objects/abstract.c#L1508) first checks if the object is a *`dict` or a `dict` subclass* - and returns false in that case. Otherwise it returns the value of

```
s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence &&
    s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence->sq_item != NULL;
```

and since `s->ob_type->tp_as_sequence` was `NULL` for a `_SRE_Match` instance, 0 will be returned, and `PyObject_GetIter` raises `TypeError: '_sre.SRE_Match' object is not iterable`.